# Allowing User to alter Nested List/Dictionary Values

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-controls

I have a list that is holding dictionary values (the whole program is reading in lines from a text file, then storing information into a dictionary and then storing all of the "rows" of dictionary data into a list. I am running into an issue trying to figure an effective and functional way to allow for a user to input some value in the dataset that they want to remove and to allow it to do so. What I've got so far is:

```
file = open('FOLDER\\FILE.txt', "r")
strData = ""
dictRow = {}
lstTable = []

for line in file:
    k, v = line.strip().split(',')
    dictRow[k] = v.strip()

lstTable.append(dictRow)

print(lstTable)

file.close()


while(True):
    print ("""
    Menu of Options
    1) Show current data
    2) Add a new item.
    3) Remove an existing item.
""")

strChoice = str(input("Which option would you like to perform? [1 to 4] - "))
print()#adding a new line


if (strChoice.strip() == '1'):
    print("Current values in the list table are: ")
    print(lstTable)
    continue

elif(strChoice.strip() == '2'):

    newRow = {}     # Empty dictionary to hold new entries
    key = input("Enter a task to complete: ")
    val = input("Enter the priority of the task (high/average/low):  ")
    newRow[key.strip()] = val.strip()  # Formatting user input as dictionary values within newRow{}
    dictRow.update(newRow)     # Updates existing dictionary with new values (e.g. updates list/Table)

    print("The values in the list table are now: ")     # Display the results
    print(lstTable)
    continue


elif(strChoice == '3'):
    print(lstTable)
    question = input("What item do you want to remove from the list? ")

    if(question in lstTable == True):

        areYouSure = input("You selected " + question + " to be removed from the list. Continue? Y/N: ").upper()

        if(areYouSure == "Y"):
            lstTable.remove(question)
            print("You subtracted " + question + " from the list!")
            print("The values in the list table are now: ")
            print(lstTable)
        continue
```

The main issue is the last block of code at the bottom - the section with variable:

```
question = input("What item do you want to remove from the list? ")
```

When I've tested index or text entries it never gets past the if block:

```
if(question in lstTable == True):
```

And I cannot figure out how to configure things correctly so that the user can just enter the key string value and then delete that dictionary value altogether from the list based on that...Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a few problems here, let me address them one by one:

First your `lstTable` does not contain rows of the dictionary, it contains the entire dictionary, like this: [{}]

So when you do the `if question in lstTable:` you are actually comparing a string with a dictionary, as you've said, it would never go through.

The reason why option 2 works is that when you did `lstTable.append(dictRow)` at the beginning, `lstTable` actually took a reference of `dictRow` instead of values in `dictRow`. So things in `lstTable` auto updates when you change anything in `dictRow` since it's just a reference.

I suggest the following for your option 3:

```
elif(strChoice == '3'):
    print(lstTable)
    question = input("What item do you want to remove from the list? ")
    if question in dictRow:
        areYouSure = input("You selected " + question + " to be removed from the list. Continue? Y/N: ").upper()    
        if(areYouSure == "Y"):
            del(dictRow[question])
            print("You subtracted " + question + " from the list!")
            print("The values in the list table are now: ")
            print(lstTable)
        continue
```

As I said your `lstTable` only stores a reference to your `dictRow`, I would not worry about changing anything in `lstTable`. Once you add/remove items from `dictRow`, `lstTable` would display the updated `dictRow` for you automatically.

Comment: This makes sense. For the effectiveness of the program, does storing the reference to the dictionary cause any problems?

Comment: @McBraunie It doesn't, honestly I don't quite get the point of having `lstTable` in your program. Once you change/remove `dictRow`, `lstTable` would not keep your original dictionary as well, it could never serve as a backup.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
if(question in lstTable == True):
```

Use:

```
if question in lstTable:
```

Python has operator chaining, so the first expression is not doing what you expect.